# Quel serait un terme ou quelle serait une expression décrivant le fait qu’une personne n’est jamais dérangée »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Exemple:

Une esthéticienne, à l’occasion d’une consultation, demande plusieurs fois à son client si ça le dérange qu’elle le quitte momentanément, que ce soit pour répondre au téléphone, pour répondre à d’autres clients à la réception voire même pour aider une collègue et il répond toujours par la négative avec un beau sourire comme si rien ne le dérangeait. J’ai certains termes en tête, mais je ne sais pas s’ils sont tous synonymes -les dictionnaires laissent à penser qu’ils ont tous une nuance- à commencer par facile et facile à vivre, suivis par « accommodant », « complaisant » et « commode ».

À la place de ce client (disons ici facile pour faire simple), qu’auriez-vous dit?

Et le client de répondre (d’autres termes):

> Ne t’inquiète pas, je ne suis pas difficile.

> Ne t’en fais pas, je ne suis pas exigeant.

> Pas de problème, je suis d’un caractère souple.

> Il n’y a pas de quoi, je suis d’un naturel docile.

> Rien ne me dérange, je me plie sans peine aux circonstances.

> Prends ton temps, je m’adapte adroitement aux exigences d’une situation, d’autant plus que j’ai du temps devant moi.

Comment: @Lambie Merci, mais comment pourrait-on qualifier cette personne que rien ne semble déranger, toujours d’un commerce agréable sans malice ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi on m'a enlevé mon commentaire. Est-ce qu'il vous a été utile?

Comment: @Lambie Bien sûr, mais je suis toujours à la recherche de ce terme décrivant la situation que je cherche à exprimer.

Comment: A vrai dire, j'avais mis une phrase comme moi je la dirais. Et pas pour nommer la personne. Etant donné votre description avec l'esthéticienne, il me semblait que je ne dirait pas je suis (une) x, mais plutôt, je ne suis pas pressée. :) Bonne chance. J'éspère que quelqu'un d'autre pourra le trouver...

Comment: Quelques suggestions : la placidité, (pas de véritables synonymes) le flegmatisme, l'imperturbabilité, la sérénité, (TLFi)

Comment: @LPH "A  la place de ce client (disons ici facile pour faire simple), **qu’auriez-vous dit**?"

Comment: @Lambie Il aurait sûrement dit: pas grave, je suis imperturbable! Cela aurait du sens

Comment: À y penser, dans ces situations qui frisent l’impolitesse, ne jamais trouver à redire pourrait laisser croire, surtout après plusieurs récidives d’éloignement du personnel, que le client agit ainsi par complaisance.

Comment: @Lambie J'aurais aimé avoir pu penser à ce qui était dans votre premier commentaire (supprimé, je crois, parce qu'il constituait une réponse) : quelque chose comme «Je ne suis pas pressé ». Lorsqu'on est pressé, ce genre de comportement n'est plus de la tolérance mais autre chose.

Comment: J'aurais répondu ce que répondit Françoise à Mme Octave dans La Recherche : « mon temps n'est pas si cher ; celui qui l'a fait ne nous l'a pas vendu »